# What does placemarker preprocessing token mean?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I wasn't able to find information about `placemarker preprocessing token`.
I encountered this notion in [this document](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note173).

Could you please explain what it is. Some examples would be very useful as well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well the footnote you link to says that "they are temporary entities that exist only within translation phase 4". So my question to you is not, why do you need to know this? It's just an internal thing that is used during the [preprocessor phase (phase 4)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases#Phase_4) of the compilation process. There's really no need to worry about such internal things unless you are writing your own C compiler.